# Mysql Sum of Two aggregate functions Not Working

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate

Hi I want to add the result of two aggregate functions, but I'm getting "Invalid Use of Group Function". Can anyone correct the following query :

```
SELECT   mc.complaint_type_id,
         mc.complaint_type,
         sum(sum(case when c.is_solved = 1 then 1 else 0 end) + sum(case when ((c.is_solved = 0) and (c.res_user_id is null)) then 1 else 0 end)) as complaints_count,

    from  svk_apt_master_complaints mc
        left join svk_apt_complaints c on c.complaint_type_id = mc.complaint_type_id and c.is_active = 1
            and c.customer_id = 1 and c.association_id = 1

        group by mc.complaint_type_id
```

Comment: you cant use `SUM(SUM(...))` like this. What you are trying to achieve here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT   mc.complaint_type_id,
         mc.complaint_type,
         sum(case when c.is_solved = 1 then 1 else 0 end) + sum(case when ((c.is_solved = 0) and (c.res_user_id is null)) then 1 else 0 end) as complaints_count
from  svk_apt_master_complaints mc
left join svk_apt_complaints c on c.complaint_type_id = mc.complaint_type_id 
where c.is_active = 1 and c.customer_id = 1 and c.association_id = 1
group by mc.complaint_type_id, mc.complaint_type
```

You don't need `sum()` when you use `+` operator. Also, `SUM` is aggregate function.

Also, you select columns, that are not included in aggregate: `mc.complaint_type`. You need to whether include it in `group by` or just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify mc.complaint_type column in group by

```
SELECT   mc.complaint_type_id,
         mc.complaint_type,
         sum(case when c.is_solved = 1 then 1 else 0 end) + sum(case when c.is_solved = 0 and c.res_user_id is null then 1 else 0 end) as complaints_count,
from  svk_apt_master_complaints mc
left join svk_apt_complaints c on c.complaint_type_id = mc.complaint_type_id and c.is_active = 1 and c.customer_id = 1 and c.association_id = 1
group by mc.complaint_type_id,mc.complaint_type
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove nested `sums` and add `mc.complaint_type` to `GROUP BY` clause. If you need to add values of two aggregate functions use `+` operator, not an aggregate function.

```
SELECT   
  mc.complaint_type_id,
  mc.complaint_type,
  sum(case when c.is_solved = 1 then 1 else 0 end) + sum(case when c.is_solved = 0 and c.res_user_id is null then 1 else 0 end) as complaints_count,
FROM svk_apt_master_complaints mc
LEFT JOIN svk_apt_complaints c ON 
  c.complaint_type_id = mc.complaint_type_id 
  and c.is_active = 1
  and c.customer_id = 1 
  and c.association_id = 1
GROUP BY mc.complaint_type_id, mc.complaint_type
```

I've also reformatted your code and removed unnecessary parentheses.